# Swarm in particles swarm optimization (PSO) algorithm

Tags: particle-swarm

In [particles swarm optimization (PSO)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) algorithm, is it possible to use dataset to initialize the position of particles, instead of use uniform random numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by a dataset?
It is possible to incorporate some sort of knowledge into the particles at initialization to speed up the convergence of them to opima. Thats why different initialization schemes have been proposed. For example you can refer to :
Kazimipour, Borhan, Xiaodong Li, and A. Kai Qin. "A review of population initialization techniques for evolutionary algorithms." Evolutionary Computation (CEC), 2014 IEEE Congress on. IEEE, 2014.
You should note that in real-world optimization problems we do not have much information about the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to initialize swarm particles with the dataset values instead of random initialization. You need to select random samples from  dataset and need to assign it to the position vector of the swarm particle.

## Initialisation of swarm particles

```
class Particle:
    position=[]
    velocity=[]
    pbest=[]
  
    
    def __init__(self):
          for i in range(rows): // rows is number of sample in your dataset
            
                                       
             self.position=Training_dataset[i,:]
             self.velocity=np.random.rand(rows,columns) 
             // columns is number of dimensions or features in dataset
                                   
               self.pbest=self.position
                


for i in  range(no_of_sample_in_dataset):
    
            p=Particle()              
            swarm.append(p)
```